# Custom age limit for iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

iTunes connect doesn't allow you to set an age limit without selecting certain parameters through trial and error. None of the content that would be on my app is graphic or actually requires restricted use. But I would like to know if you can still set an age requirement (16 for instance). Or will doing that prevent the app from getting approved by limiting use?

edit: Thanks for the answers. Now can a limit still be put in the app? Ie, the same way vine or the budweiser app "enforces" an age limit. Budweiser, for instance, is a 21+ app but in the app store it says 17+.

Comment: There is nowhere in iTC to actually do this so no, you can't. The age limit is purely set by the content using regional age restriction laws in each country the app is sold in.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control that you only want your application to be available to 16 years or older. You can only pick one of the age group that they provide.

Excerpt from [Apple on rating](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html)

**4+**: Apps in this category contain no objectionable material.

**9+**: Apps in this category may contain instances of the following content that may not be suitable for children under the age of 9:

- Infrequent or mild occurrences of realistic violence
- Infrequent or mild profanity
- Infrequent or mild mature, suggestive, or horror-themed content
- Frequent or intense cartoon or fantasy violence

**12+**: Apps in this category may contain instances of the following content that may not be suitable for children under the age of 12:

- Infrequent or mild medical or treatment-focused content
- Infrequent or mild references to alcohol, tobacco, or drug use
- Simulated gambling
- Infrequent or mild sexual content or nudity
- Frequent or intense profanity
- Frequent or intense realistic violence
- Frequent or intense horror-themed content

**17+**: Apps in this category may contain instances of the following content that may not be suitable for children under the age of 17:

- Unrestricted web access, such as with an embedded browser
- Gambling or contests
- Frequent or intense mature or suggestive content
- Frequent or intense medical or treatment-focused content
- Frequent or intense references to alcohol, tobacco, or drug use
- Frequent or intense sexual content or nudity

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Now can a limit still be put in the app? Ie, the same way vine or the budweiser app "enforces" an age limit. Budweiser, for instance, is a 21+ app but in the app store it says 17+.

Comment: How does it know if you're under 21?

Comment: I just install the Budweiser app by AB InBev and the first thing the app does is ask for my age. If I enter an age below 21, I get the message that I must be of legal drinking age to use the app.